# Design Pattern to transform object to detailed version

Tags: java, design-patterns, java-8

Lets say I have an object Foo and I wish to transform it to a ExtendedFoo object. In order to do so, I have to augment certain aspects of Foo to have more detail. The details are fetched from a helper class. See below for an example:

```
public class Foo {
   String name;
   IBar bar;
}

public class ExtendedFoo {
   String name;
   IBar bar; // this has to be an extendedBar implementation.
}



public interface IIBar {
   public int getId();

   default int getType()
   { 
      return null;
   }
}

public class Bar implements IBar {
   public int getId();
}

public class ExtendedBar implements IBar {
   Bar bar;

   public int getId() { 
      bar.getId()); 
   }

   public int getType(){};
}

public static Helper {
   public static ExtendedBar convert(Bar bar) { 
      // makes some db calls to get type info to create an Extended Bar
   }
}
```

Is there a design pattern or some Builder esque approach to create a FooConverter that internall has all the info to convert a Foo->ExtendedFoo using the Helper etc where I can just do the following:

```
List<Foo> foos;

List<ExtendedFoo> extendedFoos = FooConverter.get().process(foos).transform();
```

Keeping in mind, that in the future, I may add to Foo other simple -> detailed transformations within Foo like a IBizz with a SimpleBiz and ExtendedBiz implementations

Comment: What you are looking for is the [Decorator design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Comment: Definetly decorator

Comment: I was trying to avoid inheritance if possible. Another detail I should add is that the Extended version of the Foo object will never be accessed in code. It will be serialized and consumed for an api into json using Jackson

Comment: in your example extended foo has same attributes with foo, is that really what you need?

Comment: Yes it's meant to build on top of foo

Comment: Unless your `Foo` and `ExtendedFoo` implement the same interface, this is not a decorator. I've heard people call this _presenter_ pattern, but it's basically just a broken decorator. As for mapping objects to other objects, there's many tools like Dozer, Orika etc.

Comment: This pattern is called Frameworkeritis. You’ve chosen an inappropriate JSON generator that requires an input that you don’t have and instead of choosing a different method, that allows to directly export your extended data, you’re calling for another framework to serve the inappropriate output method’s needs. I’m quite sure that you’ll find something that does that transformation, at least 90% of it. For the then-missing part, you can search for another framework…

Comment: so you are just asking how to create a Function<Foo, ExtendedFoo> fooConvertor so that you can transform a collection?


`foos.stream.map(f -> fooConverter(f)).collect(Collectors.toList());`